# Use Nsubstitute for Registering or Configuring for IOC container

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nsubstitute

I have a custom IOC container which accepts Interface and Concrete type as parameter to register. In my project I have registered the configuration as mentioned in below code. Can you help me someone how to register in unit testing project using NSubstitute?

IOC -Conatincer.cs

```
Register<Intf, Impl>();
```

Application - Configuration.cs

```
Register<ICustomer,Customer>();
```

Unit Test Application -   CustomerTest.cs

```
Register<ICustomer,StubCustomer>(); -I want something like this
var substitute = Substitute.For<ICustomer>(); but It provides something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can have the concrete instance to be resolved by Unity and then have NSubstitute properties/methods available on it.

Since your intention is do unit testing, you need to use the NSubstitue resolved instance because only with that instance you will be able to configure the properties/method to return objects or check if calls were received.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of using like Concrete class, As a workaround added One more OverLoaded method for Register(), and passing as a parameter

Container.cs

```
 public class IOCContainer
 {
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> registrations = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();
    public static void Register<TService, TImpl>() where TImpl : TService
    {
        registrations.Add(typeof(TService), () => Resolve(typeof(TImpl)));
    }
    public static void Register<TService>(TService instance)
    {
        registrations.Add(typeof(TService), () => instance);
    }
    public static TService Resolve<TService>()
    {
        return (TService)Resolve(typeof(TService));
    }
    private static object Resolve(Type serviceType)
    {
        Func<object> creator;
        if (registrations.TryGetValue(serviceType, out creator)) return creator();
        if (!serviceType.IsAbstract) return CreateInstance(serviceType);
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("No registration for " + serviceType);
    }
    private static object CreateInstance(Type implementationType)
    {
        var ctor = implementationType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var parameterTypes = ctor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToList();
        var dependencies = parameterTypes.Select(Resolve).ToArray();            
        return Activator.CreateInstance(implementationType, dependencies);
    }
}
```

Configuration.cs

```
IOCContainer.Register(Substitute.For<IProvider>());
IOCContainer.Register(Substitute.For<ICustomer>());
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for you is to use one tool that allows you to implement the **Auto-mocking Container** pattern, it is a unit test pattern that can be used as a solution to the problem: "How can unit tests be decoupled from Dependency Injection mechanics?"

For more details about this pattern, you can see this article: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/

The concrete tool that I recommend you is *AutoFixture*, it is more to create fake objects in for your tests, but it also provides *Auto-mocking Container* functionalities.

Here is how I use it with NSubstitute in my projects:

Required libraries: *NSubstitute*, *AutoFixture*, *AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute*

```
[TestClass]
public class BuildingServiceTest
{
    private IFixture fixture;
    private IBuildingRepository repository;
    private BuildingService sut;
    private IBuildingServiceValidator validator;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
        repository = fixture.Freeze<IBuildingRepository>();
        validator = fixture.Freeze<IBuildingServiceValidator>();

        sut = fixture.Create<BuildingService>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CreateAsync_WithInvalidBuildings_ReturnsBadRequest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var buildingForCreationDto = fixture.Create<BuildingForCreationDto>();
        var validationResultWithErrors = CreateValidationResultWithErrors();
        validator.Validate(Arg.Any<CreateBuildingCommand>()).Returns(validationResultWithErrors);

        // Act
        var actual = await sut.CreateAsync(buildingForCreationDto);

        // Assert
        actual.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        actual.Errors.Should().BeEquivalentTo(FailureDto.FromValidationFailures(validationResultWithErrors.Errors));
    }
}
```